# How to identify fast movement

Tags: android-sensors, android

I want my Android application to be notified when the user is moving fast.
(lets say faster then 5 meter/second)

It must be battery efficient - so I can not use GPS for example, but can use a sensor.
Latency is not very important - it can be up to 30 seconds after reaching a fast speed.
I am only interested in continues movement. fast tilting the device can be ignored.

How can this be done ?

Comment: Did you have a look at the Activity detection API of the Google Play Services?
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity.html

Comment: you can user Accelerometer for the same, if you dont want to continue with GPS, read about it http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html

Comment: I already use activity detection - but it's irrelevant for speed, and actually very unreliable. regarding accelerometer - how can I use it to detect a constant fast movement?